# How does Spring Security handle JSESSIONID with various Session Creation and Session Fixation combinations?

Tags: java, spring, jsessionid, spring-session, stateless

I have a J2EE REST-based app using Spring Security 4.0.1.RELEASE. Needless to say, Spring documentation on `sessionCreationPolicy` and `sessionFixation` is sparse, aside from targeted questions here on StackOverflow.

I'm using a Java-based config for Spring Security like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(secureEnabled=true, prePostEnabled=true, jsr250Enabled=true, order=1)
public class DefaultSecurityBeansConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
            .sessionFixation().migrateSession()
            .and()...; // additional config omitted for brevity
    }
}
```

I'd really just like to know what behavior to expect from Spring, as it relates to `JSESSIONID`, given all possible combinations of `sessionCreationPolicy` and `sessionFixation`.

Possible values in the `SessionCreationPolicy` enum are `ALWAYS`, `NEVER`, `IF_REQUIRED`, and `STATELESS`.

Possible values for session fixation are `newSession`, `migrateSession`, `changeSessionId`, and `none`.

Thank you.

**NOTE**: What prompted this question is that I am *not* seeing a new `JSESSIONID` on every request when I have `sessionCreationPolicy` set to `IF_REQUIRED` and `sessionFixation` set to `changeSessionId`. A `JSESSIONID` is correctly created, but is maintained across requests thereafter. I generalized my question about all combinations to hopefully help others in a similar situation with slightly different settings.

Answer (score 3):

It's important to keep in mind that Spring Security doesn't always have full control of the `HttpSession`. It can create one itself, but it can also be provided a `Session` object by the container.

For `SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED`, the docs state:

> Spring Security will only create an HttpSession if required

In your particular case, you're not seeing a new JSESSIONID for every request for at least 2 possible reasons:

1. With your current configuration, Spring has the option of creating a `Session` if it needs one.
2. `SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED` also appears to allow Spring Security to use the `Session` it is provided with. Your container might be providing this object if this is the case, and so the session is maintained across multiple requests (as is expected if you're in a session).

If you wanto to disable #1, use `SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER`:

> Spring Security will never create an HttpSession, but will use the HttpSession if it already exists

The only `SessionCreationPolicy` that will ensure that Spring Security uses NO SESSIONS is `SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS`.

As regards SessionFixation, it only comes into play when you have multiple sessions for one user, after authentication. At this point, the `SessionCreationPolicy` is somewhat irrelevant.

`SessionCreationPolicy`: used to decide when (if ever) to create a new session

SessionFixation: once you have a session for a user, what to do with the session if the user logs in again

Hope this helps!